# Checking if an object has a property and accessing it

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript (and js) and this is probably basic:

```
const myObj = {
    "name": "Johnny",
    "age": 29
}


const accessProperty = (key : string) => {
    if(key in Object.keys(myObj)) {
        // TODO: access myObj.key...
    }
}
```

1. How do I access the property of `myObj` that is represented by `key`
2. Is this the right way to check if `key` is indeed a property of `myObj`?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? That way you won't need an "access property" function

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How do I access the property of myObj that is represented by key

You can access the property via myObj[key]

2. Is this the right way to check if key is indeed a property of myObj?

Someone posted a link to the optional chaining operator. This is probably the best way to go. There are times when you want to iterate through the keys of an object (mostly when you're trying to figure out what it is) but in general it is hard to create meaningful code for keys that you're not expecting, so again using the optional chaining operator is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You use the dot syntax to access object fields, that don't contain restricted characters (like space or `/`). If your field is an arbitrary string or a variable, you can use the square brackets syntax:

```
return myObj[key]
```

You might also find optional chaining operator `?.` useful, since it returns undefined instead of throwing an Error, when you are accessing an invalid object field:

```
const obj = {
  field: "value",
}

console.log(obj.field2); // => Error
console.log(obj?.field2); // => undefined
```

You can also use it with square brackets:

```
obj?.['someField']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `myObj[key] // may be undefined or raise an error`
2. `key in myObj` operator `in` checks if the left-hand operand is a key of the right-hand operand. Calling `Object.keys()` will give you an array of keys, which is number-indexed and may result in a false positive if key is a number that is within array length.

Comment: This helped me, Thanks. 

But using myObj[key] result in an error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type .....   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type .... 
Found this article that proposed a fix:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-element-implicitly-has-any-type-expression#:~:text=The%20error%20%22Element%20implicitly%20has,one%20of%20the%20object's%20keys.

Comment: @AviramShubeili Then you have to strictly type your `key` as `keyof typeof myObj` not just any `string`. You can also declare a type `type myObjType = typeof myObj` for later use